# Error at firmware update

Tags: firmware

I got this error when run this firmware update command. Before this update was succesfully completed by this command: `sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get upgrade`

```
pi@Raspi-2 ~ $ sudo rpi-update
Raspberry Pi firmware updater by Hexxeh, enhanced by AndrewS
Performing self-update
ARM/GPU split is now defined in /boot/config.txt using the gpu_mem option!
Updating firmware (this will take a few minutes)
error: rev-list died of signal 11
fatal: The remote end hung up unexpectedly
```

Comment: What happens when you run `sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get upgrade` again?

Comment: `0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 0 not upgraded.`

Comment: could be a memory issue - check that you have 30-50Mb of free RAM (free -h) before you run rpi-update. I recommend you update you copy of rpi-update, too.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I removed the git package and reinstalled it. The problem was solved.

Comment: Strange. You can mark this as the correct answer in a couple of days.